# How to use default spaceship operator with a std::string member

Tags: c++, clang, c++20

I have a struct with a few POD types and one string member. I want to use the default spaceship operator to allow equality operations of my struct, but I'm having some issues with the string member. As far as I can tell, there should be support for `<=>` for `std::string`, but in practice it seems like this isn't the case.

I have a minimal reproducing  example, and the resulting warning that I get from clang (version 14) below. Strangely, in godbolt this example produces no warning/error, even going as far back as clang 12 (https://godbolt.org/z/b65s9oMGf).

I'd really appreciate some pointers in where my misunderstanding is, because I'm pretty confused about this one.

```
#include <compare>
#include <string>

enum class MyEnum
{
    ZERO = 0,
    ONE = 1
};

struct MyStruct
{
    float a{};
    int b{};
    std::string c{};
    MyEnum d{};

    auto operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
};

int main()
{
    MyStruct my_struct;
    MyStruct my_other_struct;

    if(my_struct == my_other_struct)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

```
$ clang --std=c++20 -Werror test.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                      
test.cpp:16:10: error: explicitly defaulted three-way comparison operator is implicitly deleted [-Werror,-Wdefaulted-function-deleted]
    auto operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
         ^
test.cpp:13:17: note: defaulted 'operator<=>' is implicitly deleted because there is no viable three-way comparison function for member 'c'
    std::string c{};
                ^
1 error generated.
$ clang --version                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
```

Comment: Apple clang is normally behind on library support for newer features.  Apple clang is a fork of "regular" Clang.

Comment: If you need only equality comparison, try to define default equality operator, It should be defined for `std::string` and it should work.

Comment: If you change `auto` to `std::strong-ordering`, does it compile? I have no idea if this version of clang supports that particular feature, nor do I have a way of checking.

Comment: @sklott I'm actually needing a std::set<MyStruct>, so it needs to have all comparison operators. I probably should have included that in the example in the question, sorry! I know I can just write my own comparison operators I was just trying to use a shortcut with the shiny new C++20 features!

Comment: @Barry wow it does compile with that! Fantastic, I never would have guessed to try that out. Thanks so much

Answer (score 6):

Based on the comments, it appears that this version of clang along with its standard library:

- does implement the language feature for `<=>`, but
- does not yet implement the library additions for `<=>` (specifically adding `<=>` for `std::string`).

When you write:

```cpp
struct MyStruct
{
    float a{};
    int b{};
    std::string c{};
    MyEnum d{};

    auto operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
};
```

What a defaulted `<=>` means is to do a member-wise comparison using `<=>`, returning the value for the first member that compares unequal. When you use `auto`, that is asking the compiler to deduce the comparison category for you - but unlike typical use of `auto` (where all the return types have to be the same, and `auto` deduces to that one type), here we take the minimum of all the comparison categories. For example, if we had one member whose `<=>` returned `weak_ordering` but another whose `<=>` returned `strong_ordering`, a defaulted `<=>` would return `weak_ordering` (rather than not compile). Basically - it does what you probably want it to do, in the way you'd expect.

But - sometimes defaulting `<=>` isn't sufficient, if one of your members don't actually provide `<=>` *yet* (as in this case). In that situation, it'd be tedious to have to manually write all the comparisons out. So for that reason, there's another way that you can default `<=>` (from [P1186](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1186r3.html)): you can explicitly provide a comparison category:

```cpp
struct MyStruct
{
    float a{};
    int b{};
    std::string c{};
    MyEnum d{};

    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
};
```

What this means is, rather than simply doing member-wise `<=>`, we do something a little more involved:

- if the member has `<=>`, use it. And it has to meet the comparison category requirement (in this case, it would happen to fail because `float`s compare with `partial_ordering`, which doesn't meet the `strong_ordering` requirement - so it would have to return `partial_ordering`).
- if the member *doesn't* provide `<=>`, we synthesize a three-way comparison from `==` and `<`.

So in this case:

```cpp
struct MyStruct
{
    float a{};
    int b{};
    std::string c{};
    MyEnum d{};

    std::partial_ordering operator<=>(const MyStruct&) const = default;
};
```

would behave like:

```cpp
std::partial_ordering operator<=>(const MyStruct& rhs) const {
    // a and b provide <=>, so use it
    if (auto cmp = a <=> rhs.a; cmp != 0) return cmp;
    if (auto cmp = b <=> rhs.b; cmp != 0) return cmp;

    // c doesn't yet, so synthesize one
    if (auto cmp =
        (c == rhs.c ? partial_ordering::equivalent : 
         c < rhs.c  ? partial_ordering::less :
         c > rhs.c  ? partial_ordering::greater :
                      partial_ordering::unordered); cmp != 0) return cmp;

    // and d does, so use it
    return d <=> rhs.d;
}
```

The advantage of this language feature (as I laid out in that paper) is that once `std::string` does provide `<=>`, your implementation will pick it up automatically and be more efficient (cause the above really isn't a great implementation for string, you'd want to do `c.compare(rhs.c) <=> 0`), without you having to do all the work yourself.

Comment: In the last condition of that cluster of conditional statements, why is `partial_ordering::unordered` being compared to `0`?